# JPackage Wrong Version (%JAVA_HOME% set to correct directory)

Tags: java, jpackage

Please help. I'm having issues syncing up my JDK and jpackage versions for creating standalone java programs. The JDK version and the runtime version being included with jpackage are mismatched (JDK16 programs being paired with JDK15 runtimes).

Typing `java -version` into the command line, it matches up with the current `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable configuration, showing JDK16.0.2 (located at `C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2`). This is working correctly.

However the problem becomes more apparent when I type `jpackage --version`, it reports that it's using JDK15.0.1 - which as far as I know, I've never installed and I'm unsure of where it's running from. This is a problem, since I need to be able to build Java16 programs with jpackage. As it is now, this results incompatible runtimes and JAR files.

[image]

I've been googling to no avail. I can't compile my JDK16 programs into installers because it keeps trying to use JDK15.0.1 for the runtime.

For now, I've managed to bypass this strange and seemingly locked configuration by accessing JDK16's jpackage exe manually this way and adding the commands after:

`“C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\jpackage.exe”`

Any advice is helpful. Perhaps this temporary workaround will be helpful to anyone else with the same problem down the line.

Comment: Don't post screen shots of error messages, etc.  Copy and paste the text into the question itself.

Comment: These aren't error messages. I'm showcasing how jpackage has it's Java version confused.

Comment: What is the %JAVA_HOME% environment variable set to?

Comment: They are **etcetera**.  I know what you are doing.  But posting screenshots is against the rules.  Read this: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Comment: *"`java -version` is showcasing the current `%JAVA_HOME%` environment variable working correctly"* - That is an incorrect statement.  That `java` command does not use or depend on `%JAVA_HOME%`.  In fact the `java -version` output ONLY tells you that the version of `java` on your `%PATH%` is Java 16.

Comment: I've tweaked the question to include all of the commands used; at this point the image is merely there as a visual aid to show the problems/results I'm describing in the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the Windows `where` command to find out what the `jpackage` command is actually resolving to.  It seems clear that `jpackage` without the full path name is resolving to `jpackage` in a **different** installation of Java.

Note that `%JAVA_HOME%` does not determine how the Windows `cmd.exe` resolves commands.  Command resolution is done according to `%PATH%`.

The symptoms you describe:

- `jpackage` says `%JAVA_HOME%` is incorrect but `%JAVA_HOME%` refers to Java 16
- `jpackage -version` says Java 15 (not Java 16)
- `"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-16.0.2\bin\jpackage.exe"` works

are all consistent with your `%PATH%` being incorrect ... and that you *do* have a Java 15 installation on your machine, and it is on the `%PATH%` ahead of, or instead of the Java 16 installation you are trying to use.

Note `jpackage` is no longer an "incubator" tool in Java 16.  It has been promoted to full support; see [JEP 392: Packaging Tool](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/392).   So the warnings about incubator mudules are also consistent with `jpackage` resolving to the wrong Java installation.

---

This really boils down to understanding what the Windows `%PATH%` variable is and how it effects the behavior of Windows command shells.  (It is analogous to `$PATH` in Linux, UNIX and Mac OSX command shells.)